# One URL redirecting to another on Ubuntu 21.10 impish

Tags: 21.10, redirect, url

So I recently setup a github pages site. When I visit the site at `https://example.github.io`(Obviously that's not the real url) on my phone(Or any device other than my computer), it works fine. However, when I try and visit the site on my computer(Ubuntu 21.10 impish), it hangs for a while, and then redirects me to another domain that I own(We'll call it `example1.com`), which then times out as I don't have anything there. This is pretty weird, and I thought it had to do with the configuration of my pages site, but the fact that it works on other devices makes me believe it has something to so with Ubuntu. Maybe I changed something a while back that I forgot about? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just to note, I've already checked `/etc/hosts` and there's nothing abnormal there, and definately nothing pointing to `example1.com`

Comment: Do you have something in `/etc/hosts` that might be creating this issue? If you have custom records in your `hosts` file that contain *only* IPv4 definitions, then the hang can be the result of an IPv6 DNS lookup timeout.

Comment: @matigo Just checked, nothing abnormal in `/etc/hosts`, and definately nothing pointing to the domain